# Using sys.argv for lists in command prompt

Tags: python, list, command, arguments, system

My code with an `input("Enter data")` works, however once I change it to `sys.argv`, it doesn't. Any advice?

This is the program code:

```
import sys
try:

    listOfNumbers = list(sys.argv[1])
    listOfEvenNumbers = []
    listOfOddNumbers = []
    for x in listOfNumbers:
        if x % 2 == 0:
            listOfEvenNumbers.append(x)
        elif x % 2 != 0:
            listOfOddNumbers.append(x)

    countOfEvenNumbers = len(listOfEvenNumbers)
    countOfOddNumbers = len(listOfOddNumbers)
    sumOfEvenNumbers = sum(listOfEvenNumbers)
    sumOfOddNumbers = sum(listOfOddNumbers)
    highestNumber = max(listOfNumbers)
    lowestNumber = min(listOfNumbers)
    differenceBetweenNumbers = highestNumber - lowestNumber
    sumOfCenteredNumbers = sum(listOfNumbers) - highestNumber - lowestNumber
    countOfCenteredNumbers = len(listOfNumbers) - 2
    centeredAverage = sumOfCenteredNumbers/countOfCenteredNumbers
    print("The sum of all even numbers is %i, the sum of all odd numbers is %i,the difference between the biggest and smallest number is %i, the total number of even numbers is %i, the total number of odd numbers is %i,the centered average is %i.")% (sumOfEvenNumbers, sumOfOddNumbers, differenceBetweenNumbers, countOfEvenNumbers, countOfOddNumbers, centeredAverage)

except:
    print("Your input is invalid!")
```

This is the line being used in command prompt:

```
evenOddCalculator.py 1,2,3,4
```

It gives the result:

```
Your input is invalid!
```

Comment: try evenOddCalculator.py 1 2 3 4, with space not comma.

Comment: nope, it gives the same results.

Comment: So, in general, wrapping a huge block of code in a `try-except` is not great because you can never be sure *where* the exception is coming from. Even *moreso* if you have a "bare except" clause. Try to wrap the minimal amount of code with the `try-except`, and *explicitely catch* the exception you are expecting, e.g. `except ValueError:`, `except KeyError` etc...

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work by doing this:

```
strOfNumbers = sys.argv[1]
listOfNumbers= [int(x) for x in strOfNumbers.split(',')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input is invalid because your list contains the commas (',') as well.
In order to remove them, you can use the following line:

```
listOfNumbers = list(sys.argv[1].split(','))
```

Comment: It still gives the result: "Your input is invalid!"

Comment: @SarahCollins it is a bit hard to debug because you have such a large "try" condition.
What does listOfNumbers contain after putting list(sys.argv[1]) inside it?

Comment: This is what I did.

Program code:
strOfNumbers = (sys.argv[1])
    listOfNumbers = list(strOfNumbers)
    print listOfNumbers

Command prompt-line
\evenOddCalculator.py" 12345
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
Your input is invalid!

Comment: @SarahCollins I am sorry but it is not very clear. Does listOfNumbers contain the string "\evenOddCalculator.py" 12345 ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'] " inside it?

Comment: It does not.


What I'm saying is I ran the following code in the command prompt.
"\evenOddCalculator.py" 12345 ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'] "

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code -

```
import sys
try:

    listOfNumbers_str = list(sys.argv[1:])
    #print listOfNumbers_str
    listOfEvenNumbers = []
    listOfOddNumbers = []
    listOfNumbers = [int(i) for i in listOfNumbers_str]
    #print listOfNumbers

    for x in listOfNumbers:
        if x % 2 == 0:
            listOfEvenNumbers.append(x)
        elif x % 2 != 0:
            listOfOddNumbers.append(x)

    countOfEvenNumbers = len(listOfEvenNumbers)
    countOfOddNumbers = len(listOfOddNumbers)
    sumOfEvenNumbers=sum(listOfEvenNumbers)
    sumOfOddNumbers=sum(listOfOddNumbers)
    highestNumber=max(listOfNumbers)
    lowestNumber=min(listOfNumbers)
    differenceBetweenNumbers = highestNumber - lowestNumber
    sumOfCenteredNumbers = sum(listOfNumbers) - highestNumber - lowestNumber
    countOfCenteredNumbers = len(listOfNumbers) - 2
    centeredAverage = sumOfCenteredNumbers/countOfCenteredNumbers
    print("The sum of all even numbers is %i, the sum of all odd numbers is %i,the difference between the biggest and smallest number is %i, the total number of even numbers is %i, the total number   of odd numbers is %i,the centered average is %i.")% (sumOfEvenNumbers,sumOfOddNumbers,differenceBetweenNumbers,countOfEvenNumbers,countOfOddNumbers,centeredAverage)

except:
    print("Your input is invalid!")
```

Few things that I changed -

1. **sys.argv[1:]**

Gives all the element from index 1 to end

2. **listOfNumbers = [int(i) for i in listOfNumbers_str]**

sys.argv returns an array of String elements and not integers, I m using list comprehension here to build a list of integers from the list of String.

Running the program - >

```
$ python calc.py 1 2 3 4
['1', '2', '3', '4']
[1, 2, 3, 4]
The sum of all even numbers is 6, the sum of all odd numbers is 4,the difference between the biggest and smallest number is 3, the total number of even numbers is 2, the total number of odd numbers is 2,the centered average is 2.
```